# How do I call Python function using typescript

Tags: python, typescript, rest

I want to call API functions in python that return strings through typescript.

I have tried PythonShell, with no luck. I didn't get any errors, but I wasn't getting any values back from python and I was not getting any evidence to suggest that the python was getting the value sent from typescript.

Dummy.py

```
print("Hello World", flush=True, end='')
```

hello-world.ts
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

```
const sensor = spawn('python', ['dummy.py']);
sensor.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    sensor.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });
    sensor.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });
    sensor.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log(`Python process ended with code: ${code}`);
    });
});
```

I only get "Python process ended with code: 0" when I run this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the libary "subprocess"

```
import subprocess

def run_python_script(script, args):
    result = subprocess.run(["python", script] + args, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return result.stdout
```

And in TypeScript, you can use this Python function to run your script:

```
import { run_python_script } from "./your-python-module";

async function runScript(script: string, args: string[]): Promise<string> {
    return run_python_script(script, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the following solution:

First of all it is good to mention that you will not be able to call a python function in TypeScript by instantiating its class. This wont happen, you will need to call the python function as if you were going to execute a scritp(what indeed it actually is) passing the python file path, python function name and its arguments.
Bearing this in mind, you are gonna need to do a logic in your Python file to execute the desired function(in case you have more than one function), as I will show below.

> For this solution I have three classes, as below:

- Caller.ts(works only as a caller for the TypeScript(PythonRunner.ts));
- PythonRunner.ts(has the logic to run the python script)
- PythonLibrary.py(is the python file which contains the functions I want to execute)

Caller.ts:

```
import { PythonRunner } from "./PythonRunner";

let functionName:string = "My Python Function";
let functionArguments:any= 'My Python Function Arguments';
let scriptPath:string= 'My Python File Path'

let pythonRunner = new PythonRunner(scriptPath,functionName,functionArguments);
```

PythonRunner.py

```
import {spawn, spawnSync} from 'child_process';

class PythonRunner{
    functionName:string;
    scriptPath:string;
    argument:any;

    constructor(functionName:string,scriptPath:string,argument:string){
        this.functionName= functionName;
        this.scriptPath= scriptPath;
        this.argument= argument;
    }    

    runPythonFuntions(scriptPath:string,functionName:string, argument?:any){
        const python_process = spawnSync('python',[scriptPath,functionName,argument]);

        if (python_process.status == 0) {
            console.log('python script executed with success. Exit code:' + python_process.status)
        }else {
            console.log('python script executed with exit code:' + python_process.status)
            console.log('python script execution info:' + python_process.stdout)
            console.log('python script execution info:' + python_process.stderr)
        }
    }
}

export {PythonRunner}
```

PythonLibrary.py

```
@keyword("My Python Function")
  def my_python_function(self, received_argument):
      logger.info(received_argument)

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print("Function name was not informed.")
else:
  function_name= sys.argv[1]
  args= sys.argv
  args_number= len(args[2])  

if function_name == "My Python Function":     
  class_instance.set_path(args[2])
```